# How to define the argument type in Vue 3 TSX?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, tsx

I want to define a function which use a slot in a component. Because it is a function, so I use TSX to write it:

```
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper.vue"

function wrapComponent(InnerComponent: ?) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <InnerComponent />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

`Wrapper` is a plain Vue Component using Vue single file component. And argument `InnerComponent` should also be the type defined bye Vue single file component. If I define the type of argument `InnerComponent` is type `Component` from 'vue', it will complain `TS2604: JSX element type 'InnerComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.` The demo code is below:

```
import { Component } from "vue"
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper.vue"
import App from "./components/App.vue"

function wrapComponent(InnerComponent: Component) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <InnerComponent /> <!-- it complains the error above -->
    </Wrapper>
  )
}


wrapComponent(App) // not complains, it means App is type Component
```

So, how to define the argument type in Vue 3 project using TSX?